# MySQL optimize user permission verification

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a MySQL database 5.7. The USER can SUBSCRIBE to a CHANNEL that contains PLACES. So there is the scheme of the DB :

```
channels (TABLE)
  id INT UNSIGNED(10)
  name VARCHAR(256)

places (TABLE)
  id INT UNSIGNED(10)
  name VARCHAR(256)
  channelId INT UNSIGNED(10)

subscriptions (TABLE)
  id INT UNSIGNED(10)
  name VARCHAR(256)
  userId INT UNSIGNED(10)
  channelId INT UNSIGNED(10)

users (TABLE)
  id INT UNSIGNED(10)
  name VARCHAR(256)
```

I have an API to get the information of a place. The user asks with his credentials for a placeId, I verify his credentials.

Then I get the channelId of the place

```
SELECT channelId FROM places WHERE id = *inputId*;
```

Finally, with the userId I verify if he's subscribed with the channel

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE channelId = *channelId* AND userId = *userId*;
```

I've got the channelId by the previous request and the userId by the first one, when I'm verifying his credentials. It makes 3 requests at the end, 3 select.

Is there any other efficient way to do it? I do not have much knowledge about JOIN but if that can make the system more efficient then please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following join:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscriptions s
INNER JOIN places p
    ON s.channelId = p.channelId
WHERE
    p.id = <input> AND
    s.userId = <input>;
```

If I read your question correctly, then the `channelId` actually is not an input but rather the `id` of the `places` table is an input.